# Support of Fourier transform and Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a set of finite measure. Here let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ denote the Fourier transform.

Q: If the support of $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is contained in $X$, then is the support of $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)$ also contained in $X$?

I am not really sure how to even approach this problem. I feel like the answer is no, but cannot come up with any counter-examples. Perhaps this is a simple question, but I am not seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: From the comments below I know that we have $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(-\xi)$. After some playing around I think if $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is supported on $X$, then this implies that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)$ is supported on $-X$ ($-X = \{-x: x \in X\}$). Is this correct?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you know the formulas for $\mathcal{F}$ and it's inverse?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, I do. $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = \int f(x) \cdot e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} \, dx$ and   $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(\xi) = \int f(x) \cdot e^{2 \pi i \xi x} \, dx$

Comment: Can you relate $\mathcal F(f)$ to $\mathcal F^{-1}(f)$?

Comment: @StefanLafon: Is the relation you mean this one? $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(-\xi)?$

Comment: Yes. Now what does each of the statements above mean in terms of $\mathcal X$?

Comment: So if $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = 0$ for $\xi \notin X$ then by the relation this means that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(\xi) = 0$ when $\xi \notin X$. But doesn't this mean that the function $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(-\xi)$ is supported on $X$, and not necessarily $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(\xi)$?

Comment: Yes, asking both problems is redundant ... your question will be better perceived if you delete one of them ;)

Comment: @LL3.14: Thanks for the recommendation, just updated it!

Comment: Didn't think Asuka would turn into a math undergrad after spending her teens being an eva pilot

Comment: @StefanLafon: Sorry there was a typo in my previous comment concerning the question, it should have been $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(-\xi) = 0$ when $\xi \notin X$.

Comment: Your latest edit seems correct to me. I think you got it right.

Comment: I think if $X \in \mathbb{R}$ with $X$ compact-supported will imply that the support of the Fourier Transform is going to be $\mathbb{R} \neq X$ so it won't going to work for any $X$ "within" the reals... at least is what I unerstand from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting#Bandlimited_versus_timelimited)